# Core Data - Migrating to new Model Name

Tags: ios, swift, core-data-migration, nspersistentstore, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I have an app in the store now that I am updating. I did a lot of Core Data changes, including changing the name in both 'lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel' and 'lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?'.

How can I properly use Core Data Migration to ensure when an existing user downloads the update, the app doesn't crash on them?

**Old**:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyApp-Model" withExtension:@"momd"];

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
```

**New**:

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("My-App", withExtension: "momd")!

let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("My-App.sqlite")
```

Comment: Why don't use same old name for sqlite file?

Comment: Apple has pretty good documentation for this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html

Comment: Yeah, why did you change the file names. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Refer this documentation, i found it useful for core data migrations http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844